# Is there a way to assert type without duplicating code? - Typescript

Tags: typescript

I wrote up this code where you can see the issue I'm having with the solution that I currently have.

```
type Keys = "foo" | "bar";

type Item = {
  id: string;
}

type Dated = {
  date: string;
  item: Item
}

function isItem(param: any): param is Item {
  if (!param) return false;
  return (param as Item).id !== undefined;
}

type AddDated = {
  item: string | Dated;
  key: Extract<Keys, "foo">
}

type AddNonDated = {
  item: Item;
  key: Extract<Keys, "bar">
}

function addItem(payload: AddDated | AddNonDated) {
  // Do something
}

function manageItem(item: AddDated["item"] | AddNonDated["item"], key: Keys) {
  if (isItem(item) && key === "bar") {
    addItem({
      item: item,
      key
    })
  } else if (!isItem(item) && key === "foo") {
    addItem({
      item: item,
      key
    })
  }

}
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oCIBmB7LaoB90AjAQwCc0BuAKGtEigElgIBbFKAb2qigEsAJgC4oCYGT4A7AOY0AvrXrQAIiRYCO3XgLUQRYiTJq8+LViOZtqC6hgCukgMbA+WSfwSXWACjDkS5lAkkiAAlCJ+ZAEeTGZcPPwYUN4AhJEBoVBkEMB2ZO4YJAA2CBDGWTl57r7+7CRIXqEAdIJQKcioDgIQGFIQAvKK4NAAggICquqaCaZs+uJS0gRQk-3lANbwIgCiAB7iJM4APHCIADTo2LgAfNZDDGMCAHJuqxqoWvxmFmYbW1B7A7HU4IC5oUgUW42exOFxuILjLw1EBFLAkYRQR5vZaPF6SN6ZT4AeiJKywoiwrByAAtFndbA5nK53KxgiRpBAkbNAljdAIANpobloAC6OPGeLeguFIoumxAIhBhJmSW8fE8ZjVZkyADIdVB5SgOsRyGhlbxeOiBEjPhavnN7awzgk7fKXVA5KEEnIoBAStA+KqUuqudqoHqDfAjahMDgzfE7Vabe6TN9Hc67bw3XbPd7aHIgA)

Basically what I want to know is if it's possible to have the `manageItem` function with type assertion but without having to duplicate the code that is going to use the asserted variable.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to allow `item` and `key` to mismatch in the first place.  Why not just do something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w2pz9m) where `item` and `key` are correlated and generic?  Would that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing about your use case?

Comment: I tried to generalize my question, so your solution didn't work for what I wanted, but  your solution does improve on what I asked here. Feel free to write up an answer and I'll mark it as accepted :)

Comment: As for my problem, I was using Redux Toolkit and in the reducer function I can't add the generic `<K>` to the `addItem` function because it changes the type of another param to any and I can't type it myself.